# Fill down/increment by 1 if line is the same as line above it

Tags: python, loops, increment

I am having a hard time trying to fill down a series of numbers based on the content of a line and the line immediately above it. I have a text file containing several lines of text, and I want to check if a line is equal to the line above it. If it is equal, then add 1, and if not then use 1. The input text is:

```
DOLORES
DOLORES
GENERAL LUNA
GENERAL LUNA
GENERAL LUNA
GENERAL NAKAR
GENERAL NAKAR
```

and the output I want is:

```
1
2
1
2
3
1
2
```

I tried this but it gives a different result:

```
fhand = open("input.txt")
fout = open("output.txt","w")

t = list()
ind = 0

for line in fhand:
    t.append(line)

for elem in t:
    if elem[0] or (not(elem[0]) and (elem[ind] == elem[ind-1])):
        ind += 1
    elif not(elem[0]) and (elem[ind] != elem[ind-1]):
        ind = 1
    fout.write(str(ind)+'\n')
fout.close()
```

How can I have the result that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem is that you *say* that you want to check for identical lines, but your code deals with individual characters.  Trivial tracing of  your program shows this.
See this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).

You need to deal with lines, not characters.  I've removed the file handling, as they are immaterial to your question.

```
t = [
    "DOLORES",
    "DOLORES",
    "GENERAL LUNA",
    "GENERAL LUNA",
    "GENERAL LUNA",
    "GENERAL NAKAR",
    "GENERAL NAKAR",
    ]

prev = None    # There is no previous line on the first iteration
count = 1
for line in t:
    if line == prev:
        count += 1
    else:
        count = 1
        prev = line
    print(count)
```

Output:

```
1
2
1
2
3
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit you conditions like this :

```
fout.write(str(1)+'\n')
for elem in range(1,len(t)):
    if t[elem]==t[elem-1]:
        ind += 1
    else:
        ind = 1
    fout.write(str(ind)+'\n')
```